# Output posterior distribution from bayesian network in R (bnlearn)

Tags: r, machine-learning, bayesian-networks

I'm experimenting with Bayesian networks in R and have built some networks using the bnlearn package. I can use them to make predictions for new observations with predict(), however I would also like to have the posterior distribution over the possible classes. Is there a way of retrieving this information?

It seems like there is a prob-parameter that does this for the naive bayes implementation in the bnlearn package, but not for networks fitted with bn.fit.

Thankful for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of bnlearn.
predict function implements prob only for naive.bayes and TAN.

---

In short, because all other methods do not necessarily compute posterior probabilities.

---

[bnlearn] :: predict returns the predicted values for node given the data specified by data. Depending on the
value of method, the predicted values are computed as follows:
a)parents b)bayes-lw
When using bayes-lw , likelihood weighting simulations are performed for making predictions.

Hope this helps. :)